# how to get google search history back in safari 6

Tags: macos, safari

I am very annoyed about safari 6 doing away with the google search history. Is there anyway to get it back? Just to be clear I am talking about when you google something and then you need to go back to that same search. In safari 5 you could click on the the arrow in the google search bar and it would give you a drop down menu of all your latest google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a new *window* or *tab*, clicking on the **magnifying glass** will drop down the *recent searches* menu.

[image]

This menu will drop dow, too, if you just type a *space* or empty the *search bar* by deleting.

Comment: You can also press the down arrow key when the location bar is empty.

Comment: @LauriRanta Doh! Forgot about that!